# Property 'pixiOverlay' does not exist

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, angular8

In my Angular 8 project I have to put some markers on a map so I'm using [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/). As sometimes there are a few thousand markers I decided to use [Leaflet.PixiOverlay](https://github.com/manubb/Leaflet.PixiOverlay) to avoid the performance issues. So I installed and imported all the libraries:

```js
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import 'leaflet-pixi-overlay';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
```

So far so good. The problems come when I try to draw a marker (I'm following the example from [Leaflet.PixiOverlay](https://github.com/manubb/Leaflet.PixiOverlay#readme)).

```js
const pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay(function(utils) {

  //

}, pixiContainer);
pixiOverlay.addTo(this.map);
```

I get `L.pixiOverlay` highlighted in red and this compiling error:

> ERROR: .... /pages/maps/map.component.ts(86,29): error TS2339:
>   Property 'pixiOverlay' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   import("C:/Users/ .... /node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you call L.pixiOverlay in a component's method ? If yes, what method ?

Comment: Inside a method called `initMap()` which is called in the `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: I try to reproduce your problem in stackblitz. Could you provide a small chunk of your code ? (the best would be an entire stackblitz)

Comment: I put here ([link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpkqcc)) the code. For some reason stackblitz can't find the leaflet package. I tried to reinstall it with no success. Anyway, I fixed the issue adding this: const pixiOverlay = **(L as any)**.pixiOverlay(function(utils) {. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: I've created a whole new Angular project and can't reproduce your problem. Do you have a public repo i could clone in order to test ? Also, does't a ng build works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem and managed to miss the [solution in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359124/property-pixioverlay-does-not-exist#comment104935697_59359124). So just so other people won't miss it like I did:

The solution is to replace

```
const pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay(...)
```

with

```
const pixiOverlay = (L as any).pixiOverlay(...)
```